# Does it matter to specify callback as another callback's dependency in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Here are my hooks.

```
export function useContractFactory() {
  const { provider }: any = useWallet();

  return useCallback(
    (address: string, abi: any) => {
      return new EthersContract(address, abi, provider);
    },
    [provider],
  );
}

export function useTokenActions() {
  const createContract = useContractFactory();

  const isERC20 = useCallback(async (address: string) => {
    const contract = createContract(address, erc20TokenABI);

    return isTokenERC20(contract);
  }, []);
  
  return {
    isERC20
  } 
}
```

`createContract` is a `callback` as you can see. Now, TypeScript and ESLint compile with warnings.

> React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency: 'createContract'.
> Either includes it or remove the dependency array

Should I specify `createContract` as a dependency for `isERC20` callback? or there's no need to have a `callback` at all? What do you think?

Comment: Since you want `isERC20` to do something different as soon as the wallet provider changes, yes it's necessary.

Comment: Does this mean that `isERC20` contract gets created 2 times ? because it renders 2 times , but the 2nd time would be the actual correct function. Correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add `createContract` to a dep array.
Based on this [React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)

> useCallback will return a memoized version of the callback that only changes if one of the dependencies has changed

It doesn't matter if it will not change but the callback itself will consider it